# Firing Events when Objects are Added Or Removed From a List

Tags: .net

What is the data type that will fire an event when an object is added or removed from a list?

`ObservableCollection<T>` almost suits my need, but the problem is in addition to `CollectionChanged` event ( which is all that I need), it also fires `PropertyChanged`, which is something I don't need at all. The fact that the object type `T` is required to inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a hindrance for me as I don't implement `T` class.

Is there such a data type in .Net 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` does **not** require `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

<strike>*If* `T` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it will forward `PropertyChanged` events.

However, this is not required.</strike>

**EDIT**: `ObservableCollection` does not use`INotifyPropertyChanged` at all, except to notify changes to the `Count` and `Item[]` properties of the collection itself.
It won't even try to forward child PropertyChanged events.

Comment: yes that's right, but the `T` requires `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and *that's* the problem.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: I think what SLaks is saying is: no, it doesn't. Where are you seeing that `T` is constrained to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes you are right. It happened that there is a component that has the same `ObservableCollection` class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not roll your own class? Just inherit from System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection and
override the InsertItem, SetItem, RemoveItem etc. methods to throw an event.